# Add a subject line to django-contact-form

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to add a subject line to Django-Contact-Form (https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-contact-form/overview), but I'm having no such luck. The module is by default set to read the subject from a text file, but I want the user to be able to write it into a form. Here's what I'm editing in forms.py:

```
        def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if request is None:
            raise TypeError("Keyword argument 'request' must be supplied")
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(data=data, files=files, *args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request

        name = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                       label=u'Name')
        email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,
                                                           maxlength=200)),label=u'Email')
        subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100,
                       widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                       label=u'Subject')
        body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs=attrs_dict),
                          label=u'Message')

        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

        recipient_list = [mail_tuple[1] for mail_tuple in settings.MANAGERS]

       # subject_template_name = "contact_form/contact_form_subject.txt"

        template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.txt'

        _context = None

        def message(self):
        """
        Renders the body of the message to a string.

        """
        if callable(self.template_name):
            template_name = self.template_name()
        else:
            template_name = self.template_name
        return loader.render_to_string(template_name,
                                   self.get_context())

        def subject(self):
        """
           Renders the subject of the message to a string.

        """
                                                     maxlength=200)),label=u'Email')

        return self.subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-contact-form/src/1d3791fa4dfb/contact_form/forms.py), the text file (contact_form/contact_form_subject.txt) is not simply just read in, it's rendered as a template and then inserted into the result. The subject template is passed the full context:

```
    By default, this context includes:

    * All of the validated values in the form, as variables of the
      same names as their fields.

    * The current ``Site`` object, as the variable ``site``.

    * Any additional variables added by context processors (this
      will be a ``RequestContext``).
```

You should be able to reference the form value within the subject template very easily by making the template something like {{ subject }} (if the form field is named "subject").